# Suitable laser for Engraving

Tags: lasers

I have made a CNC machine from CD drive and want it to use for engraving purpose. which laser would be best for this job?

Comment: More information is required. What material do you wish to engrave?

Answer (score -1):

If the Wattage of semiconductor blue laser will be about 1 W (as those laser from blue-ray CD) then plastic and wood may be carved and mild aluminium may be scratched  (matted). But in the metal will no deep hole. For such activity is needed at least 10W CO2. If the cutting is aim, then at least one order more, but if the cut target is sth like railways rails then one more order of magnitude stronger.

Comment: For railway rails one should probably consider a waterjet cutter ;)